# GTK:how to prevent users from changing my app theme

Tags: user-interface, gtk, themes

so if i make an app using GTK and users install a GTK theme can this change my app theme ?? 
if yes how to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying a bundled copy of the default GTK theme in a GtkCssProvider inside your app with the highest priority. However, you should consider not doing it. Some themes are useful for users with accessibility needs, and you would be excluding those users from using your app.

Comment: well i didn't understand so much 
but so there is no way i can do it with just code i mean a function in GTK or something